# Copy one list of files to another

Tags: windows

I have a list of files extracted from a table in a SQL database. The file can be either a delimited text file or an excel spreadsheet, whichever works best.

The file looks like this

```
sourcePath1\fileName1, destPath1\fileName1
sourcePath2\fileName2, destPath2\fileName2
sourcePath3\fileName3, destPath3\fileName3
```

etc

One column contains the original path and filename of the files, the second column contains the desired path and filename of the files. This has been obtained using a standard REPLACE() function in the original SELECT statement.

Now I have the list(s) I actually need to copy the source file to the destination.

Is this achievable using the command line (batch or Powershell?) or via scripting or a GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon David Ruhmann's answer, the following works.  It uses `xcopy` and passes an `F` to the prompt that asks if the file is a file or folder.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (book1.csv) do (
    cmd /c echo F | xcopy "%%~A" "%%~B"
)
```

EDIT: Added tilde (~) as per @DavidRuhmann suggestion.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working. **`:)`** Just some batch notes.  1. The cmd /c is not necessary.  2. When adding quotations to paths, add the tilde to remove any existing quotes (if any) "%%~A" .  This is just an error proofing step in case quotations are already included around the paths.

Comment: Be sure to mark your answer if it solves your question.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann Thanks for following up with the additional points and for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a native Windows batch solution to parsing a comma separated value (csv) text file.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (file.csv) do (
    copy %%A %%B
)
```

Comment: This looks to be along the lines of what I need however, if the folder structure does not already exist, I receive a "The system cannot find the path specified" error. Is it possible to create the folder structure on the go?

Comment: To create a folder structure, we would have to either parse the path and use `md` before the `copy` command or as you did in your answer, use `xcopy`.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to do with a Unix shell.  Here's how you might do it with my [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm).  (The [free version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm) will do this.)  You could do something very similar with [Cygwin](http://Cygwin.org) `bash`.

The really easy way to do it would be to transform the list using [sed](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/Utilities/sed.htm) into a script where each line a `cp` operation. Then just run the script.

```
sed "s/^^/cp '/;s/, /' '/;s/^$/'/" < list.csv > copyscript.csh
copyscript
```

Here's what that `copyscript.csh` file would look like:

[image: Using sed to convert a CSV list into a list of cp commands]

Comment: Thanks for posting this.

Where would I specify the input file containing the list of files?

Comment: In my examples, I've read the list from the lines following using the `<< endExample` ... `endExample` notation.  You could read the list from a file using `< listoffilepairs`.  If you have trouble making this work, please call and I'll walk you through it.  (Yes, I support even my free version.)

Comment: @Danny I've simplified my answer to just doing it the easy way and to read from a file containing the list.  I hope that's helpful.